# Circularity in formal proof of De Morgan's laws?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I was reading about De Morgan's laws on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws . When I looked at the formal proof for the law, it seems like a circular argument is used, can someone explain to me what I'm not getting. It's this bit:

"Let $x \in (A \cap B)^c$. Then, $x \not\in A \cap B$. Because $A \cap B = \{y | y \in A \text{ and } y \in B\}$, it must be the case that $x \not\in A$ or $x \not\in B$."

I can grasp why that must be the case. But is this deduction not done using De Morgan's laws? Ie De Morgan's laws state

$\neg(P\land Q)\iff(\neg P)\lor(\neg Q)$

If $P$ stands for the statement "$x \in A$" and Q stands for "$x \in B$". Isn't the structure of the argument in the formal proof of De Morgan's Law the same as De Morgan's law itself?

Comment: Well, one is used with sets, the other logical statements. Perhaps if they derived the logical De Morgan using sets, I'd take offense, but I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: The set forms of De Morgan's laws are proven using the logic forms. (The logic forms can be proven using truth tables, I guess.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two forms of De Morgan's laws, for sets:
$$ (A\cap B)^\complement = A^\complement \cup B^\complement \qquad
(A\cup B)^\complement = A^\complement \cap B^\complement $$
and for logic:
$$ \neg(P\land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P\lor \neg Q \qquad
\neg(P\lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P\land \neg Q $$

It is common and unproblematic to appeal to the *logical* laws while proving the *set-algebra* laws. OF course one has to use a different method to prove the logical formulations; usually one just goes to truth tables for that.

Comment: (+1)Sir if we see the usual proof(done in highschool)of $(A\cap B)^\complement = A^\complement \cup B^\complement$ i think it assumes $\neg(P\land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P\lor \neg Q$. But in logic it just says that two statements have got equal truth value,it means that we are just using the validation of truthness to sketch the proof. The wikipedia article provided by OP uses the method of contradiction. $>So what i want to ask is, whether it is possible to have a direct proof with out using its equivalent statement of logic.$

Comment: The latter part of my comment is "whether it is possible to have a direct lroof without using its equivalent statement of logic ?"

Comment: Let me clear a bit what i want to say, in usual proof the following two steps are involved.

 (1)....$\forall x\;(\; [x\in (A\cup B)']\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\cup B]\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\land x\not \in B]\implies$ $ [x\in A'\land x\in B']\implies$ $ [x\in A'\cap B']\;).$

   (2)....$\forall x\;(\;[x\in A'\cap B']\implies$  $[x\in A'\land x\in B']\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\land x\not \in B]\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\cup B]\implies$ $ [x\in (A\cup B)']\;).$  note the 3rd to 4th statement of (1) and (2) ,where it uses the logic. Hence we are just proving the set identity using logic identity.

Comment: Finally i want to say sorry for this series of comments,i just wanted to know how the proof actually discovered instead of knowing a method of validating it.